# Do you know an operation in which the order of elements does not matter but repetitions is allowed?

Tags: operator-theory, mathematical-modeling

In order to present a concept in an article, I need an operation in which the order of elements does not matter but repetitions is allowed.

For example, if a have some vectors [1 2 3], [2 3 1], [1 2 3], how can denote that I'm building a multiset V = {[1 2 3], [1 2 3], [2 3 1]} (in which the order does not matter)?

If I use union:
$$
  [1\  2\  3] \cup [2\  3\  1] \cup [1\  2\  3] = \{[1\  2\  3], [2\  3\  1]\}
$$

Correct? In this case I'm missing one repetition of one element... what operation should I use?

Comment: How about addition?  If you want to do it with vectors, then component-wise addition.  $[1,2,3]+[2,3,1]+[1,2,3]=[4,7,7]$.

Comment: Actually I want something like "The set of all vectors that were seem until now", storing repetitions, hence I want as result in this example {[1, 2, 3], [1,2,3], [2,3,1]}

Comment: Your question, both in the title and in the first paragraph, does not mention anything about recovering the original elements.  In any case, what's wrong with [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)?

Comment: If you're dealing with multisets (as you said), then the union itself should result in a set that contains $[1\  2\  3]$ twice. I'm not sure there's anything left to do, to be honest.

Comment: Multisets *are* what you want. There's no point asking "what operation should I use", when you know exactly what you want the operation to do — in other words, when you have already defined the operation. You're only asking for its *name* (although that's not so clear to yourself, because you keep asking for "what" the operation "is"). Call it anything you want, but it *is* the operation you have already defined. And oh, the name you're looking for, is [multiset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Multiplicity_function).

Comment: How do I denote that I am building a multiset from some elements? should I write V = $[1,2,3]+[2,3,1]+[1,2,3]$ ?